# Prove or disprove: An integer $~a >4~$ is composite if and only $~(a−1)!≡0 ~(\text{mod} ~a)~$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> **Prove or disprove:** An integer $~a >4~$ is composite if and only $~(a−1)!≡0 ~(\text{mod} ~a)~$.

If I plug in integers for a such as $~6~$ and $~8~$, then the statement is true.

Is there any way I can prove this without using examples?

Comment: $6 \neq 0 \mod 7$. Maybe that's why?

Answer (score 4):

If $a$ is prime, then all factors of $(a-1)!$ are less than $a$, so $a \not\mid (a-1)!$ and, thus, $(a-1)! \not\equiv 0 \pmod a$. Note, by [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem), you get that $(a-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod a$.

However, if $a$ is composite, then $a = bc$ for some integers $b \lt a$ and $c \lt a$. If $b \neq c$, then both $b$ and $c$ are distinct factors of $(a-1)!$ so $a = bc \mid (a-1)!$ and, thus, once again, $(a-1)! \equiv 0 \pmod a$. The only reason there may not be $2$ distinct factors is if $a$ is a square of a prime number, say $p$, but with $p \gt 2$ since $a \gt 4$. However, in that case, $p$ and $2p$ are each less than $a$, so both are distinct factors of $(a-1)!$, giving at least $2$ factors of $p$ and, thus, $(a-1)! \equiv 0 \pmod a$.

Answer (score 0):

$~(a−1)!≡0 ~(\text{mod} ~a)~\iff(a-1)!=2\cdot3\cdot4\cdots(a-2)(a-1)=Ma$ so by Wilson's theorem $a$ cannot be prime.

If $a=\prod p_i^{\alpha_i}$ then  each factor $p_i^{\alpha_i}\le(a-1)$ excepting when $a=p_i^{\alpha_i}$.

Supposing $a\ne p_i^{\alpha_i}$ it follows that all the factors of $a$ are also factors of $(a-1)!$ then the conclusion.

When $a=p_i^{\alpha_i}$ we have $p$ and $p^{\alpha_i-1}$ are factors of $(a-1)!$. We are done.